# Issue in Loading Map on ArcGIS in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, arcgis

i'm using ArcGIS map in my ios app. I'm facing an issue in loading a map on the mapView. I'm getting my map information from the database that i have stored previously I'm trying to load the map that i had stored in database. But unfortunately they are not loading , i have printed the map info and check in console the data comes from database fine but it does not load.This is my code to call the previously saved map from database,

```
presenter?.prepareTripDataAndShowOnMap(tripInfo)
```

I have printed the tripInfo, it shows this in console,

```
BCTripInfo(id: "333764BC-427A-404E-8209-59BB18E79148", name: "tripe", ownerId: "test@bcnavxe.com", isPinned: true, status: bcnavxe.BCTripInfoStatus.notDownloaded, timestamp: 2018-07-23 11:35:04 +0000, trekFolder: "g")
```

This is how i'm getting map information from the database,

```
 static func get(fromTripInfo tripInfo: BCTripInfo, completionHandler: @escaping (BCTrip?) -> Void) {
    guard let tripDatabase = BCDatabaseMaster.shared.tripDatabasePool.getTripDatabase(withTripId: tripInfo.id) else {
        completionHandler(nil)
        print(tripInfo.id)
        return
    }
    tripDatabase.inDatabase({ database in
        do {
            guard let tripEntity = try BCTripEntity.getTrip(inDatabase: database, withTripInfo: tripInfo) else {
                completionHandler(nil)
                return
            }
            let tripGeometryEntities = BCGeometryRepositoryImpl.getAll(inDatabase: database, fromTripInfo: tripInfo)
            let trip = BCTripMapper.toTrip(fromTripEntity: tripEntity, andGeometryEntities: tripGeometryEntities)
            completionHandler(trip)
        } catch {
            completionHandler(nil)
        }
    }) { error in completionHandler(nil) }
}
```

}
How can i load the map now on mapView?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? What framework are you using (BC)? How do you interoperate BC with ArcGIS? Have you tried loading the AGSMap upon a successful callback?

Comment: Actually what am i doing is that, firstly i draw some shapes on the arcgis map and save it in my database , now i'm getting that map from database and trying to load the same map on the arcgis map

Comment: BC is basically my class name because it is starting alphabets of my app. I'm getting this data from database when i get the saved map,
BCTripInfo(id: "333764BC-427A-404E-8209-59BB18E79148", name: "tripe", ownerId: "test@bcnavxe.com", isPinned: true, status: bcnavxe.BCTripInfoStatus.notDownloaded, timestamp: 2018-07-23 11:35:04 +0000, trekFolder: "g"). Now how can i show this data in map? Using the id of that map? @achi

Comment: There's still a lot more that you'll need to elaborate before I can help answer your question. How do you plan to interoperate your above code with ArcGIS?